# Combobox databinding through code

Tags: vb.net, combobox

i have this form where i am binding data with the controls. This is my code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;Data Source=c:\users\desraj\desktop\mydb.accdb;")
        conn.Open()
        formload()

        adap = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from mytable", conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        adap.Fill(ds, "mytable")
        BindingSource1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        BindingNavigator1.BindingSource = BindingSource1


        TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "id")
        TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "myname")


        ComboBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "city_code")
        ComboBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "state_code")


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub

Public Sub formload()
    Try
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from mycity", conn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read = True
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(reader.Item(1))
        End While
        reader.Close()

        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from mystate", conn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read = True
            ComboBox2.Items.Add(reader.Item(1))
        End While
        reader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

i have 3 tables
table 1: `MYTABLE` with 4 columns
`id,myname,city_code(fk),state_code(fk)`
table 2: `MYCITY` with 2 columns
`city_code,city`
table 3: `MYSTATE` with 2 columns
`state_code,state`

For example:
`mytable` has following values
`ID` `myname` `city_code` `state_code`
1  alan  2  3
2  rock  3  1
3  brock 1  2
`mycity` has following values
`city_code` `city`
`1`  `abc` 
`2`  `xyz` 
`3`  `pqr` 
`mystate` has following values
`state_code` `state`
`1`  `lmn` 
`2`  `fgh` 
`3`  `def`

The problem is that instead of loading `combobox1` and `combobox2` with city and state, it loads `city_code` and `state_code`.
How can I load `city` and `state` in `combobox1` and `combobox2`, as i am having their foreign keys in `mytable`?

Comment: are you saying you want CBO1 to have something like {Alaska, AK; Alambama, AL...} so you can assign city and state to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first be binding the parent list to the ComboBox by setting the DisplayMember, ValueMember and DataSource.  The ValueMember is the name of the PK.  You then use DataBindings to bind the SelectedValue to the FK column of the child table, e.g.

```
With cityComboBox
    .DisplyMember = "city"
    .ValueMember = "city_code"
    .DataSource = cityBindingSource
    .DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", personBindingSource, "city_code")
End With
```

Note that two different BindingSources are used.

Comment: Thank you @jmcilhinney. Actually can you tell me what is the difference between `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`.?

Comment: Why can't you just read the documentation for them both?  Look first, ask questions later... only if you actually need to.

Comment: ok....thank u...but i have one more doubt.please help me, what if i have 4 such ComboBox, where 2 combo display city and 2 display state. should i be creating 4 different bindingsource.?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want. I created a sub which you can defile in your class or any form.

```
Public Sub ComboData(ByVal FieldName As String, ByVal TableName As String, ByVal ComboBoxName As Object)
Try
        Dim conSQL As New SqlConnection
        conSQL.ConnectionString = conString1 'this is the connectionString you defined, change the name to yours.
        conSQL.Open()

        cmdSQL.Connection = conSQL
        cmdSQL.CommandText = "Select " & FieldName & " from " & TableName

        drSQL = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader()

        ' Fill a combo box with the datareader
        Do While drSQL.Read = True
            ComboBoxName.Items.Add(drSQL.GetString(0))
        Loop
        'Con.Dispose()

        conSQL.Close()
        'End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

After this just use.

```
c.ComboData("<add the field name>", "<add the table name>", <add the combobox you want to bring the desired information>)
```

I hope this is the answer, If not Update me I will edit my answer accordingly.